# Accessing a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find the answer.

To that end, I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => active
            [sid] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => expired
            [sid] => 2
        )

)
```

What I'd like to be able to do is type $arrayName["active"] and it return the SID code.  I will be using this like a dictionary object of sorts.  It's like I need to reindex the array so that it is the key/value pair that I need.  I was just wondering if there was an easier way to do it.

Comment: What if there's 3 subarrays and 2 are 'active'? an array key can only point to one "value" (even if that value is another array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert your nested arrays into a single associative array. Something like this should take your example and turn it into an associative array:

```
$assoc_array = array();
foreach( $example_array as $values ) {
  $assoc_array[$values["status"]] = $values["sid"];
}
```

You can then access the `sid` for a given `status` by using `$assoc_array["expired"]` (returns `2`)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing - now I can access the array like I want.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After seeing the others' solutions, I realize this might be bit of an overkill, but I'm still just gonna throw it out there:

```
$foo = array(
  array('status' => 'active', 'sid' => 1),
  array('status' => 'expired', 'sid' => 2),
);

// Get all the 'status' elements of each subarray
$keys = array_map(function($element) {
  return $element['status'];   
}, $foo);

// Get all the 'sid' elements of each subarray
$values = array_map(function($element) {
  return $element['sid'];
}, $foo);

// Combine them into a single array, with keys from one and values from another
$bar = array_combine($keys, $values);

print_r($bar);
```

Which prints:

```
Array
(
    [active] => 1
    [expired] => 2
)
```

Manual pages:

- [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map)
- [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys)
- [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values)
- [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine)
- [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
  function findActive($my_array){

    foreach($my_array as $array){
      foreach($array as $val){
        if($val['status']==='active'){
          return $val['sid'];
        }
      }
    }

    return false;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

access it via a loop or directly.

```
if($arrayName[0]['status'] == "active") {
   echo $arrayName[0]['sid'];
}
```

If you want to check all the SIDs

```
foreach($arrayName as $item) {
  if($item['status'] == "active") {
     echo $item['sid'];
  }
}
```

A more direct approach is just putting the loop in a function and return an array of all active session IDs

Answer (score 0):

```
$sidArr = array();
foreach($yourArr as $val) {
  if("active" == $val["status"]) {
    array_push($sidArr, $val["sid"]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

reindex would be the best

```
$arrayName = array()
foreach ($data_array as $data)
   $arrayName[$data['status']]=$data['sid'];
```

Or use a function

```
function get_sid($status)
{
    global $data_array;
    foreach ($data_array as $data) {
        if ($data['status']==$status)
             return $data['sid'];
    }
    return false;    
}
```